# Plotly click event does not work due to range of values of in a single bar of a histogram

Tags: r, plotly, dt

I have the dataframe below:

```
col1<-sample(500, size = 500, replace = TRUE)
col2<-sample(500, size = 500, replace = TRUE)
d<-data.frame(col1,col2)
```

And I create a histogram of this data frame that has click-event activated. When the user clicks on a bar the rows of the dataframe that have the relative value are displayed in a datatable. The problem is that the app works fine with a few values.  If for example my dataframe had 5 rows instead of 500 with :

```
col1<-sample(5, size = 5, replace = TRUE)
col2<-sample(5, size = 5, replace = TRUE)
d<-data.frame(col1,col2)
```

But with more values the app does not work since the plotly gives a range of values in every single bar instead of a unique value.

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("heat")
  ),
  DT::dataTableOutput('tbl4')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$heat <- renderPlotly({
        render_value(d) # You need function otherwise data.frame NN is not visible
    p <- plot_ly(x = d$col2, type = "histogram",source="subset") # set source so
    # that you can get values from source using click_event

  })

  render_value=function(NN){
    output$tbl4 <- renderDataTable({
      s <- event_data("plotly_click",source = "subset")
      print(s)
      return(DT::datatable(d[d$col2==s$y,]))           
    })  
  }           
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think the problem is similar to yesterday question :)  You are trying to compare count of histogram with your data but count doesn't exists in your data. Even for small dataset it is not working properly.

Comment: hmmm how could I add this column in a long dataset automatically and not manually?

Comment: I have added solution for you. Please let me know in case you need further details!  Basically, you need to plot histogram of count so that you can get your original data based on click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (added code to capture the count). You need to plot a histogram of count and then you can able to get your original data based on click event.

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("heat")
  ),
  DT::dataTableOutput('tbl4')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$heat <- renderPlotly({
    col1<-sample(500, size = 500, replace = TRUE)
    col2<-sample(500, size = 500, replace = TRUE)
    d<-data.frame(col1,col2)
    d=d %>%
      group_by(col2) %>%
      mutate(count = n()) # You can programatically add count for each row
    render_value(d) # You need function otherwise data.frame NN is not visible
    p <- plot_ly(x = d$count, type = "histogram",source="subset") 
    # You should histogram of count
    # set source so that you can get values from source using click_event       
  })

  render_value=function(d){
    output$tbl4 <- renderDataTable({
      s <- event_data("plotly_click",source = "subset")
      print(s)
      return(DT::datatable(d[d$count==s$x,]))           
    })  
  }           
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Screenshot from the working prototype:
[image]